# how to arrange 2*2 radiogroup

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-relativelayout, android-radiogroup

I am making an app in which I want to design the options in 2*2 radio buttons.For this I am doing the following thing but getting "android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton" error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TableRow>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:gravity="center|left"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>


<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_span="2"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"   />

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </RadioGroup>

  </TableRow>

    <Button android:id="@+id/submitbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@id/group" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/submitbtn"/>

 </TableLayout>
```

Please help in this I am stuck since morning.

Comment: RadioGroup can not contain other views but RadioButtons, Your way is not possible...

Comment: So what should be approach? I have already made the app logic now my so I am out of the option to create the radiobuttons seperately and putting on-off,I have to use RadioGroup only

Comment: Your radio group should contain only radio buttons and not a RelativeLayout. You can instead use two radio groups inside a relative layout or a linear layout. If the orientation of Linear layout is horizontal, the orientation of RadioGroup should be Vertical.

Comment: @Skynet- how to merge those two radiogroup to make them work as a single group?

Comment: it depends on what You need. You can do two radiogroups and check the selected, or, if You only want to select one of these four buttons, You can just place them without the radiogroup and deselect all other buttons by clicking on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

1.remove radiogroup.

2.take parent layout as relative

3.take 4 radio button as required

4.write onclicklistener for all radio button

5.In radio button-1 onclicklistener event disable other button and do that for other(set check for particular button and for other set unchecked)

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends on Your needs. But You can do it like this: Juste don´t use RadioGroup, instead use two LinearLayouts:

```
  <LinearLayoutLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayoutLayout>

 <LinearLayoutLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"  />

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayoutLayout>
```

Then You can refer it programatically and deselect all other buttons, if one is pressed:

```
    yourFirstRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view){

       YourSecondRadioButton.setChecked(false);
       YourThirdRadiobutton.setChecked(false);
       YourFourthRadioButton.setChecked(false);

      }

    });
```

You have to do this for all Your radio buttons. This is just a simple example, You can do it in a better way, for example with a for loop. For example, after creating RadioButtons, initialize a RadioButtons Array:

```
 private RadioButton[] radioButtons;
```

initialize after initialize all radioButtons:

```
 radioButtons = {radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3,radioButton4};
```

And the, make a setSelected(RadioButton button) method:

```
   private void setSelected(RadioButton button){

   for(int i=0;i<radioButtons.length;i++){

      if(radioButtons[i]!=button){

          radioButtons[i].setChecked(false);
      }
    }

   }
```

and call this in Your onClick():

```
  yourFirstRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view){

       setSelected(yourFirstRadioButton);

      }

    });
```

It´s possible that I have some little wrong coding here, because I can´t test it at the moment, have no IDE here. But just give it a try and come back if it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Radio Group, implements onClickListener for RadioButtons and maintain the active Radio Button Id. Like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
    android:onClick="onClickButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
    android:onClick="onClickButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"
    android:onClick="onClickButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, In ur activity implements "onClickButton" method mentioned to the OnClick attribute of RadioButtons:

```
private RadioButton checkedRadioButton;

// OnClick listener for Radio Buttons
public void onClickButton(View view) {
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view;
    if (checkedRadioButton != null) {
        checkedRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    radioButton.setChecked(true);
    checkedRadioButton = radioButton;
}

// Get the Active radio button ID
private int getCheckedRadiButtonId() {
   if (checkedRadioButton != null) {
        return checkedRadioButton.getId();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

U can get the current active radioButton Id using getCheckedRadiButtonId.

Comment: I have already completed the app if I gowith this solution then I have to code it from strach which is hectic anyways thanks for the help cheers!!